# I dont know what to declare in axios promise parameters?

Tags: typescript, promise, axios

How do I write this code in typescript ?

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.interceptors.response.use(null, error => {


});
```

I tried doing this:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((null:any), (error: any) => {
//didnt work
```

error: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type '((value: AxiosResponse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the response callback:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (resp: AxiosResponse) => resp,
  (error: any) => {
    // ...
  }
);
```

Since all responses are routed through this interceptor and only the returned response is further processed, you're required to specify a response-callback.

Comment: thanks, it worked, after i imported AxiosResponse from axios why did they dislike the question ? its that bad ?

Comment: It's the sort of question that could've probably been answered by looking into the documentation of axios and people are annoyed at the little effort you put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: they wont give typescript based documentation, can u please upvote to balance ? pls, it worked on JS without doing AxiosResponse